# How to split filename strings and convert to a datetime in R

Tags: r, string, date, datetime

In R I'd like to split file names in the format "a_b_c_d.jpg"
For example:
`20190104_080314_2048_1700.jpg`

The Date: 2019.01.04 and time 08:03:14 is important to me. The other numbers (2048= pixel, 1700= filter) are not.

So I need the a and b value.

If I use strsplit I get: `[1]"a" "b" "c" "d.jpg"`, but i want `[1] a [2] b` only.

And in the end i want to use the `[1] date` and `[2] time` and put it together into one value: `2019-01-04T08:03:14`

Has anyone an idea how to do this?

Thanks for helping me with programming for my astrological research about the sun activity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get the pieces of the string you need.

```
library(stringr)

x <- '20190104_080314_2048_1700.jpg'

str_replace(x, '(^.{4})(.{2})(.{2})_(.{2})(.{2})(.{2}).*', '\\1-\\2-\\3T\\4:\\5:\\6')
#[1] "2019-01-04T08:03:14"
```

The expression is anchored to the start of the string, then gets the first four characters, then the next 2 characters etc.  The first bracket is capture group 1 (i.e. \1)

Comment: All the best with your sun research!

Comment: Good solution - the OP didn't actually specify that they wanted a proper datetime object. Strictly speaking, your answer is more correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps here. First is to split the string, as you suggest, and second to convert those outputs to a datetime object.

Step 1:
`strsplit` produces a list object. To access individual parts of that list, you need to `unlist()` it and then call the specific elements you're after.

```
t <- "20190104_080314_2048_1700.jpg"

t.split <- unlist(strsplit(t, "_"))[c(1,2)]
# [1] "20190104" "080314"
```

Step 2: 
Now you can convert these two strings to a datetime object of your choice. Using `lubridate` makes it pretty easy:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms(paste(t.split[1], t.split[2]))
# [1] "2019-01-04 08:03:14 UTC"
```

or you can use the base R function `strptime`:

```
strptime(paste(t.split[1], t.split[2]), format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
# [1] "2019-01-04 08:03:14 PST"
```

Note the difference in the default timezones, and be sure to specify the right one (both functions take a `tz=` argument).

Comment: Thank you very much, the first part worked. I want to use strptime but it sais t.split not found. Do you know what's the problem?

Comment: Yes, sorry - I failed to copy the object I created with the split up string. See edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I took Tony Ladsons version because i need exactly that T08:03:14 and not the PST but thank you too for your effort! :)